# Zebra puzzle in Scala

Tags: python, scala

I'm trying to work through Udacity's CS212 using Scala but had trouble with the Zebra Puzzle,

Some of the concepts in python just doesn't convert to Scala easily, especially for a beginner like me.

[image: SS of python codes]

These are the codes I've managed so far,

```
  val houses = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  val orderings = houses.permutations

  def imright(h1: Int, h2: Int): Boolean = {
    if (h1 - h2 == 1) true
    else false
  }

  def nextto(h1: Int, h2: Int): Boolean = {
    if (math.abs(h1 - h2) == 1) true
    else false
  }
```

`the houses = [first, _, middle, _. _] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` stumped me.
Furthermore, how do i express the `for (red, green, ivory, yellow, blue) in orderings` in Scala? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: `def imright(h1: Int, h2: Int) = h1 - h2 == 1`, the same goes to nextto.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion, its so much neater.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

```
val houses = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val List(first, _, middle, _, _) = houses
```

and

```
for (List(red, green, ivory, yellow, blue) <- orderings)
```

respectively.  Also, note that in Scala these sorts of destructurings must be assigned to variables starting with a lower-case letter; upper-case indicates that it is instead supposed to match an existing variable (or throw an exception if it does not!).

Comment: Hi, Rex, my compiler gave the following error for the first snippet. Similar error is found for the 2nd one too...                   Multiple markers at this line
 - constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) required: List[Int]

Comment: @adsisco - Sorry, I forgot to add `List` in there.  Fixed now.