# Einstein's puzzle in Scala

Tags: python, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zebra puzzle in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090600/zebra-puzzle-in-scala)

This problem had been bothering me for the past two days.

What is the Scala way of solving such puzzle? I've tried to implement the nested for loops shown in python in Scala below but it just doesn't work. The loop is already giving me 0 results on the 2nd constraint. This is probably due to me being new to Scala and missing out some details.

If anybody got any idea, please help my poor soul, thanks.

[image]

heres my code,

```
  val houses = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  val orderings = houses.permutations
  val List(first, _, middle, _, _) = houses

  def imright(h1: Int, h2: Int) = h1 - h2 == 1

  def nextto(h1: Int, h2: Int) = math.abs(h1 - h2) == 1

  for (List(red, green, ivory, yellow, blue) <- orderings if imright(green, ivory))
    for(List(englishman, spaniard, ukrainian, japanese, norwegian) <- orderings;
      if englishman == red; 
      if norwegian == first) println(orderings.length)
```

Comment: the same questions was asked by me, its clearly different.

Comment: You spelled ukrainian wrong. So I'm not surprised at all ^)

Comment: Also there is a blood in your Scala code. That intrigues me...

Comment: fixed the spelling if that is going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  val houses = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  val orderings = houses.permutations.toList
  val List(first, _, middle, _, _) = houses

  def imright(h1: Int, h2: Int) = h1 - h2 == 1

  def nextto(h1: Int, h2: Int) = math.abs(h1 - h2) == 1

  for (List(red, green, ivory, yellow, blue) <- orderings if imright(green, ivory))
    for(List(englishman, spaniard, ukranian, japanese, norwegian) <- orderings
      if (englishman == red)
    ) println(Map(
      "englishman" -> englishman
      ,"red" -> red
      ,"norwegian" -> norwegian
      ,"first" -> first
    ))
```

Comment: Changed `val orderings = houses.permutations.toList`